# How can I update Pyspark DataFrame column values under two column conditions using Bitwise or bit and function?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, bitwise-operators

I need to update a column (`Flag`, containing many flags, each flag is `2^n` `int` number, add up) in a `pyspark` dataframe under two conditions, i.e. `column(Age)` value >= **65** and column `Flag` does not contain the new flag value which is checked by a Bitwise or bit and function: (`Flag` & `newFlag`) == 0

I have demonstrated my work using a sample dataframe and python script(plelase see it below) but encountered an error message.
the error message is: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`Flag` AND 2)' due to data type mismatch: '(`Flag` AND 2)' requires boolean type, not int;

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType`
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# create a data frame with two columns: Age and Flag and three rows
data = [
(61,0),
(65,1),
(66,10)  #previous inserted Flag 2 and 8, add up to 10, Flag is 2^n
]
schema = StructType([ \
StructField("Age",IntegerType(), True), \
StructField("Flag",IntegerType(), True) \
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
#df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

N_FLAG_AGE65=2
new_column = when(
   (col("Age") >= 65) & ((col("Flag") & lit(N_FLAG_AGE65) == 0)), 
   col("Flag")+N_FLAG_AGE65     
).otherwise(col("Flag"))
df = df.withColumn("Flag", new_column)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Please add your sample input and expected output datasets. It will the forum to understand your use case in a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

after input source df is constructed, the first display line of `df.show(truncate=False)` should be

```
+---+----+
|Age|Flag|
+---+----+
|61 |0   |
|65 |1   |
|66 |10  |
+---+----+
```

My updating algorithm is to check both columns (Age and Flag), if `age >=65` and Flag bit function does not contain N_FLAG_AGE65, we update Flag field by `Flag = Flag+N_FLAG_AGE65`. Thus, the expected result should be

```
+---+----+
|Age|Flag|
+---+----+
|61 |0   |
|65 |3   |
|66 |10  |
+---+----+
```

I think that the original syntax of "new_column" conditional expression won't work with `df = df.withColumn("Flag", new_column)`

I did syntax change, it works now for the following code by adding a new constant `lit(N_FLAG_AGE65)` called `column(Flag65_exp)` and used `expr("case when Age>=65 and Flag & lit(N_FLAG_AGE65)=0` then `Flag+lit(N_FLAG_AGE65) Else Flag End")` in `df.withColumn("Flag",expr("..."))`

```
%python
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, 
StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# create a data frame with two columns: Age and Flag and three 
rows
data = [
(61,0),
(65,1),
(66,10)  #previous inserted Flag 2 and 8, add up to 10, Flag is 
2^n
]
schema = StructType([ \
StructField("Age",IntegerType(), True), \
StructField("Flag",IntegerType(), True) \
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
#df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

N_FLAG_AGE65=2
df=df.withColumn('Flag65_exp', lit(N_FLAG_AGE65))
df = df.withColumn("Flag", expr("case when Age>=65 and Flag & 
lit(N_FLAG_AGE65)=0 then Flag+lit(N_FLAG_AGE65) Else Flag End"))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
#source df
+---+----+
|Age|Flag|
+---+----+
|61 |0   |
|65 |1   |
|66 |10  |
+---+----+

#updated df 
+---+----+----------+
|Age|Flag|Flag65_exp|
+---+----+----------+
|61 |0   |2         |
|65 |3   |2         |
|66 |10  |2         |
+---+----+----------+
```